# how do i put an external javascript file into my html document?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, external

for an assignment I need to write a code to display an array in alphabetical order and count the items in the array. I can do this fine but the last requirement is to put the JavaScript into an external file. how do I do this exactly? below is my code and what i need to put in an external file but I have no idea how to do this.

This is the finished code but i need everything in the script tags to be in an external file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

   <h2>Question 2 Array</h2>

   <p id="array"></p>

   <button onclick="alpha()">Sort alphabetically</button>
   <button onclick="count()">Count items in array</button>

   <script>
   var products = [" Printer", " Tablet", " Router", " Keyboard", " Mouse", " PC"];
   document.getElementById("array").innerHTML = products;

   function alpha() {
      document.getElementById("array").innerHTML = products.sort();
   }

   function count() {
      document.getElementById("array").innerHTML = products.length;
   }

   </script>


</body>

</html>
```

just to narrow it down here is the things to go external.

```
 var products = [" Printer", " Tablet", " Router", " Keyboard", " Mouse", " PC"];
     document.getElementById("array").innerHTML = products;

     function alpha() {
        document.getElementById("array").innerHTML = products.sort();
     }

     function count() {
        document.getElementById("array").innerHTML = products.length;
     }
```

Comment: Why don't you actually learn javascript? This is a website where people ask questions that do not have answers in books, tutorials and such. You clearly do not know nearly enough html and javascript to be using this website. You can start your learning here http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: Judging by the javascript and html above, I think I have learnt some javascript and html. Maybe I cant find the answers in videos or books and want to ask someone head on? your comment was not helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in *myFile.js* and link this file to your HTML file, like this :

```
<script src="myFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks that is really helpful. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="../js/yourjavascriptfile.js"></script>
```

Put inside a .js file and link it within the head tags, the src=" **place of file** " should be the relative/absolute path to where the file is located.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="path_to_external_file"></script> <!-- here comes your javascript file path -->
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really simple

```
<script src="path to your .js file"></script>
```

As an example create a JS file called site. Then your js file should be site.js. Put your all javascript codes in that file.

Then call it in html `<head>` after all css. Keep in mind if you are using jQuery put you js file after jquery include.